# Rasberry Pi - how do I install TUN driver?

Tags: kernel, ubuntu, modules

I want to install OpenVPN Server on my Raspberry Pi 2, following the same steps I used in a virtual machine running Ubuntu 19.10
Ubuntu works fine, but Raspberry goes on error during the installation of TUN driver.

Here are my steps:
- install TUN driver with [this script](https://gist.github.com/jmnwong/8959194). I had to add on Raspberry Pi:

```
sudo apt install raspberrypi-kernel-headers
```

It seems to work, but if I list the interfaces with:

```
ifconfig
```

I don't see the tun0 interface, while on Ubuntu I see it. `reboot` didn't solve it.

---

Here are some details:

- Raspberry Pi 2 model B
- Raspbian Buster (release date 2020-02-13, Kernel version: 4.19)

Anyone can help me?
Thanks!

Comment: `sudo ip tuntap add dev tun0 mode tun`

Comment: The tun module is available w/ the stock kernel.

Comment: @goldilocks - no deprecation message that I can see

Comment: Please delete your duplicate question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JaromandaX Oh yeah!  Debian does not have that; wikipedia notes ["*many* Linux distributions have deprecated..."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ifconfig#Release_status), not all.  My bad, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Though not a direct answer [the PiVPN Project here](https://www.pivpn.io) has installed fine on slightly older models before.

If you link was actually to [enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/jmnwong/8959194) then be aware that is for a six year old version of Ubuntu and not the latest version of Debian.